# vagrant will not use rbenv ruby version

Tags: ruby, bundler, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm using the Vagrant box:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14292474/vagrantboxes/precise64-ruby-1.9.3-p194.box

It has ruby1.9.3 installed under rbenv.  I'm trying to test a rails app and in the chef-solo provisioner I have (among other things), this block:

```
execute 'install' do
  action :run
  command "bundle install --path #{node.app_name.lib_path}/vendor/bundle --binstubs"
  cwd node.app_name.path 
end
```

rbenv is installed under the vagrant user and instructed to use 1.9.3 globally.  For some reason, when bundler is run during *vagrant up* it still uses 1.8.7 which is only found in /opt/vagrant_ruby.

How can I tell vagrant that I want to use the rbenv ruby to perform all tasks.  Do I need to pass something in the *env* option of the *execute* block?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, the reason is that `$RBENV_ROOT` is not added to `$PATH` via the vagrant ssh connection. I tried adding it to `/etc/profile` but got no love, in fact it killed vagrant's ability to ssh in at all

Answer (score 0):

First start to get the path of bundle in your server:

```
$ which bundle
/opt/rbenv/shims/bundle
```

Then, knowing that in chef when you included the rbenv cookbook, the constant `RBENV_ROOT` is equal to /opt/rbenv, modify your command like this:

```
command "#{RBENV_ROOT}/shims/bundle install --path #{node.app_name.lib_path}/vendor/bundle --binstubs"
```

So you ensure to use the correct version of bundle when installing.

A second thing you can do is to add the path for rbenv (which can be located in /etc/profile.d/rbenv but that depends on your installation) on top of the ~/.bashrc of the user you use with chef-solo

For example, if you are using a use "deployer", edit /home/deployer/.bashrc to have on top of the file:

```
#Rbenv path for remote shells
source /etc/profile.d/rbenv.sh    # <--- adapt this to your installation

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return    # <--- remote shell (ssh connection) will stop at this line
```